# React, complex useState syntax confusion

Tags: reactjs, function, syntax

I have a function in `useState` that I'm having a hard time understanding, how it's working. In short, where's the body of the function `setSelectedAccount`. Following are the places in code:

1. In `app.jsx` inside `useState` hook:

   ```
   const[selectedAccount, setSelectedAccount] = useState({});
   ```
2. In `app.jsx` in render method inside a component being used:

   ```
   <Account
     setSelectedAccount = {setSelectedAccount}
     //more code
   ```
3. Inside another file `Account.jsx` (component):

   ```
   const FormObserver = props => {
      let {accounts, setSelectedAccount, setFormvalues} = props;
      //more code
   ```
4. Inside `Account.jsx` in `useEffect` hook:

   ```
   useEffect(() =>
     setSelectedAccount(
        find(accounts.data, account => values.selectAccount === account.id)
     );

     values.varX = "";
   }, [values.selectAccount]);
   ```

**Summary:** `selectAccount` is just value from a dropdown.

**Question:** where is the body of the method `setSelectedAccount` that sets `SelectedAccount` values? Is `find` method inside the `useEffect` hook the body of the `setSelected` function?

Comment: The body is in React's internal's - it's not implemented by the script-writer using React. The `find` part is just an argument passed to the function.

Comment: 2 questions:-
1. so what is the purpose of the setSelectedAccount function where find is the argument? I know there's custom code involved, but the purpose of the useState is something I'm confused with here if set function is not setting the value.
2. What is the purpose of useState if the value of selectedAccount is not being set by the function "setSelectedAccount"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no body, basically this

```
 setSelectedAccount(
     find(accounts.data, account => values.selectAccount === account.id)
  );
```

is the same code as:

```
 setSelectedAccount(() => {
  return find(accounts.data, account => values.selectAccount === account.id)();
 });
```

It's just shorter to return `find` because it returns a function anyway.

I don't know what `find` is but based on the structure it is a function that returns a function, probably looks like this (lodash fp probably):

```
const find = (list, cb) => () => {}
```

Comment: Understood that there is no body. But then what's the purpose of setSelectedState in the useState hook? is "selectedAccount" getting set somehow? If not, then what's the use of this useState hook? Is "find" the end result of the setSelectedAccount function?

Comment: @user2043789 useStateHook has 2 parameters, the first one is the value, the second one is the setter function. whatever the value in `setSelectedAccount(value)` will be the value of `selectedAccount`

Comment: Got it. This is what I needed to understand. Thanks.